# Higher order lp regularization and lp least squares like regression with p>2

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, regression, machine-learning, least-squares

Is $l_p$ norm with $2<p<\infty$ used for regularization in any practical applications? Also least squares is usually used with $l_2$ norm squared. But are there any applications where $l_p$ norm is used with $2<p<\infty$? Please give the references if so.

Comment: The $\ell_\infty$ norm is sometimes used to control the largest component of a residual. For example, instead of finding a least squares solution to $Ax=b$ you could minimize $\| Ax-b\|_\infty$, if you want the largest component of the residual to be as small as possible. I haven't encountered $\ell_p$ regularization with $2 < p < \infty$ in practical applications.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to mention finiteness of p. Is $\infty >p>2$ used anywhere else?

Comment: A weighted Holder norm with $p=3/2$ appears in the market impact model in this MOSEK paper on portfolio optimization: https://docs.mosek.com/whitepapers/portfolio.pdf, section 2

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But it would be nice to see $2<p<\infty$ example.